# python chrome.driver element.text of table data not populating unless I inspect element in browser first

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Apologies, as I am a nascent coder...
Attempting to automate tasks (order processing) via selenium/chromedriver:
I am running into an issue. Since I don't understand what the problem is, I am having a difficult time fixing it.

I am attempting to get the text of an element, where that element is an item of a table.   I know exactly where that data is, and modify the CSS selector string accordingly to get it.

No exceptions are being thrown, either by my code or by upstream code.

Here is the offending code:

```
            rscSelector = '#ctl00_ctl00_contentMainPlaceHolder_MainContent_dlRSCName > tbody > tr > ' \
                          'td:nth-child({}) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > ' \
                          'span'.format(str(count+1))   # This element is 1 indexed, why?  who knows
            element = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(rscSelector)
            RSC = bD.RSCDict[element.text.strip()]
```

this is passed through a loop testing for a value in a field, then looking in a corresponding element to find the text I want.  (two separate tables with corresponding information)

What is throwing me, is, the first 4 iterations, it works, 5 and up it fails to get the text. (passes '')

Furthermore, if I manually inspect the element in chrome, then it works... with no changes to the code, same runtime?

full block of code:

```
def accept_order2(order_R, quantity, chrome, chromeHandleID, firefox, fFoxHandleID):
chrome.switch_to.window(chromeHandleID)
chrome.switch_to.frame(chrome.find_element_by_css_selector('#itemDetail'))
RSC = None
for count in range(numberOfRSCs):
    qtySelector = '#ctl00_ctl00_contentMainPlaceHolder_MainContent_rptCheckout_ctl00_' \
                  'datalstContainer_ctl{}_txtOrderQty'.format(str(count).rjust(2, '0'))  # pad string/0 indexed
    try:
        element = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(str(qtySelector))
    except ElementNotVisibleException:
        print('Double check at least 1 field has data entered into it.')
        break
    fieldQuantity = element.get_attribute("value")

    if fieldQuantity != '' and fieldQuantity != ' ' and fieldQuantity is not None:
        if int(fieldQuantity) == quantity:
            rscSelector = '#ctl00_ctl00_contentMainPlaceHolder_MainContent_dlRSCName > tbody > tr > ' \
                          'td:nth-child({}) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > ' \
                          'span'.format(str(count+1))   # This element is 1 indexed, why?  who knows
            element = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(rscSelector)
            RSC = bD.RSCDict[element.text.strip()]
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError('Origiinial Order Quantity and quantity supplied in field does not match')
```

This appears to be a bug in the chromedriver, however, I am well aware that I  do not possess enough expertise to make such a claim.

Any help would profoundly be appreciated!!!

Christopher Lund

p.s. I am not in control of the webpage in which I am attempting to work with.  and I am deliberately working with 2 browsers at the same time: firefox and Chrome. the Firefox code isn't shown for brevity sakes, as there are no issues there.

Comment: Solved:  the element was not in view.  just had to move to it first...   the clue?  4 items in view,  4 items were getting captured.